# Magento 1.7 add image in menu

Tags: magento

I make a site in magento 4wayshop.in  , Now I add image in menu Like Watches , shoes bcz many of blank space in menu. How i do it please help me. Please open the 4wayshop.in and see it.

Comment: I think you are using some extension for top. Because this is not default Magento menu layout. If so, share that extension URL.

Comment: I am using magento theme and it's link http://themeforest.net/item/pharmacy-responsive-magento-theme/4365274

Comment: go check your frontend/default/yourtemplate/page/html/topmenu.phtml on that template.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reduce Menu width according to items/links in submenu then you can update CSS thing from:
http://4wayshop.in/skin/frontend/default/ma_pharmacy/css/wide_menu.css

Line 24: `.wine_menu .container {
width: auto; /* in stead of width:100% */
padding: 1px;
padding: 3px 0 0;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 41px;
display: none;`

OR

You need to override topmenu block, follow below step to add category images in menu.

Copy: `app\code\core\Mage\Page\Block\Html\Topmenu.php`

Paste to: `app\code\local\Mage\Page\Block\Html\Topmenu.php`

Then open `app\code\local\Mage\Page\Block\Html\Topmenu.php` file and edit `protected function _getHtml` function to add category image into menu.

Hope will help!